# AJAX POST request cancelling because the page navigates away

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to make 2 requests on Submit action in a form.

1 request is sent to an external DB using an external script.

The other request however is an AJAX POST request which stores the form fields in localStorage and posts the JSON to a PHP file which then saves the data to a text file on the current server (where the form is hosted)

The issue is that the AJAX POST request gets cancelled on submit because the 1st action (external script sending data to external DB) navigates away from the current page and gives you a success/failure status of the submission.

I know this because there is a form validation in place (which doesn't stop the AJAX request) and if there is a validation error in email, the form doesn't navigate to another page but the AJAX POST request is successful and JSON data is delivered properly to the text file on the server.

Following is the HTML/JS and PHP code:

**HTML/JS:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="eloqua.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    localStorage.clear();

    $("form").on("submit", function() {
        if(window.localStorage!==undefined) {
            var fields = $(this).serialize();

            localStorage.setItem("eloqua-fields", JSON.stringify( fields ));

            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "backend.php",         
               data: fields
            });
        } else {
            alert("Storage Failed. Try refreshing");
        }
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{

var a=document.forms["EloquaForm"]["C_FirstName"].value;
if (a==null || a=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }

var b=document.forms["EloquaForm"]["C_LastName"].value;
if (b==null || b=="")
  {
  alert("Last name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }

var y=document.forms["EloquaForm"]["C_EmailAddress"].value;
var atpos=y.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=y.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=y.length)
  {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p><img src="red-asterix.jpeg"> indicates a required field</p>

<div class="form-container" style="width: 625px">
<form class="form-eloqua" name="EloquaForm" action="http://s33.t.eloqua.com/e/f2" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
<span class="form-eloqua-label"><span>First Name</span></span><input id="firstname" type="text" name="C_FirstName" />
<span class="form-eloqua-label"><span>Last Name</span></span><input id="lastname" type="text" name="C_LastName" />
<span class="form-eloqua-label"><span>Email Address</span></span><input id="email" type="text" name="C_EmailAddress" />
<span class="form-eloqua-label">Title</span><input id="title" type="text" name="C_Title" />
<span class="form-eloqua-label">Company</span><input id="company" type="text" name="C_Company" />
<span class="form-eloqua-label">ZIP or Postal Code</span><input id="postcode" type="text" name="zipOrPostalCode" />
<span class="form-eloqua-label">Country</span><select id="country" name="country">
<option value="">Please select ...</option>
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="AL">Albania</option>
<option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
<option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
<option value="AD">Andorra</option>
<option value="AG">Angola</option>
<option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
<option value="AG">Antigua &amp; Barbuda</option>
<option value="AR">Argentina</option>
<option value="AA">Armenia</option>
<option value="AW">Aruba</option>
<option value="AU">Australia</option>
<option value="AT">Austria</option>
<option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
<option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
<option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
<option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
<option value="BB">Barbados</option>
<option value="BY">Belarus</option>
<option value="BE">Belgium</option>
<option value="BZ">Belize</option>
<option value="BJ">Benin</option>
<option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
<option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
<option value="BO">Bolivia</option>
<option value="BL">Bonaire</option>
<option value="BA">Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina</option>
<option value="BW">Botswana</option>
<option value="BR">Brazil</option>
<option value="BC">British Indian Ocean Ter</option>
<option value="BN">Brunei</option>
<option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
<option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
<option value="BI">Burundi</option>
<option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
<option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
<option value="CA">Canada</option>
<option value="IC">Canary Islands</option>
<option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
<option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
<option value="CF">Central African Republic</option>
<option value="TD">Chad</option>
<option value="CD">Channel Islands</option>
<option value="CL">Chile</option>
<option value="CN">China</option>
<option value="CI">Christmas Island</option>
<option value="CS">Cocos Island</option>
<option value="CO">Colombia</option>
<option value="CC">Comoros</option>
<option value="CG">Congo</option>
<option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
<option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
<option value="CT">Cote D'Ivoire</option>
<option value="HR">Croatia</option>
<option value="CU">Cuba</option>
<option value="CB">Curacao</option>
<option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
<option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
<option value="DK">Denmark</option>
<option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
<option value="DM">Dominica</option>
<option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
</select>
<div class="form-eloqua-separator"></div>
<span class="form-eloqua-label">Annual Revenue Range</span><select name="C_Annual_Revenue1"> <option value="">Please select ...</option> <option value="0-100,000,000">0-100,000,000</option><option value="100,000,001-300,000,000">100,000,001-300,000,000</option><option value="300,000,001-500,000,000">300,000,001-500,000,000</option><option value="500,000,001-2,000,000,000">500,000,001-2,000,000,000</option><option value="2 Billion +">2 Billion +</option></select>
<div class="submit-button"><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
<div id="output"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="elqoffer" value="GGB2BContentMktg" />
<input type="hidden" name="elqchannel" value="TheMarketer" />
<input type="hidden" name="elqbq" value="14Q2" />
<input type="hidden" name="elqbc" value="UK" />
<input type="hidden" name="elqFormName" value="2013-Syndication-1372365875136" />
<input type="hidden" name="elqSiteId" value="33" />
</form>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<h1>Below is the data retrieved from SERVER</h1>
<?php
   date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago'); // CDT
   echo '<h2>Server Timezone : ' . date_default_timezone_get() . '</h2>';
   $current_date = date('d/m/Y == H:i:s ');
   print "<h2>Server Time : " . $current_date . "</h2>";

   $file_content = array();
   if ( file_exists('your_data.txt')){
       $file_content = (array)json_decode(file_get_contents('your_data.txt'));
       unlink('your_data.txt');
   }

    $file_content['users'][] = array('user'=>$_POST);
        file_put_contents('your_data.txt',json_encode($file_content));
?>
```

**LIVE VERSION of the form:** http://bhanuchawla.me/dev/redactive/marketerform/

**Text file where JSON data is posted:** http://bhanuchawla.me/dev/redactive/marketerform/your_data.txt

**NOTE:** if you get a **Submission Successful** message when you submit the form, it means that the external script on action ran successfully and not the AJAX. To test if data is submitted via AJAX check out the your_data.txt file (URL above)

How do I make sure that AJAX POST is done before the page navigates away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a form.submit() after your ajax request is completed. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit() it should bypass your event handler and get you your desired result.

```
var isSubmitted = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    localStorage.clear();

    $("form").on("submit", function(evt) {
        if (!isSubmitted) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            if(window.localStorage!==undefined) {
                var fields = $(this).serialize();

                // Not an async task so don't need promise.
                localStorage.setItem("eloqua-fields", JSON.stringify( fields ));

                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "backend.php",         
                  data: fields
                }).done(function() {
                  isSubmitted = true;
                  $this.submit();
                });
            } else {
                alert("Storage Failed. Try refreshing");
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

This is untested, so not sure if it will work properly. Although, this is a fairly convoluted way of handling things. In my head, doing an AJAX request + POST Form submit feels wrong. I'd say stick to doing 2 AJAX requests(including form submit).

Comment: Infinite loop mate. Keeps on posting to backend.php

Comment: Ok, so its not bypassing the event handler for some reason. This is a bit hacky but what you can do is set a global variable/flag that keeps track of whether the Ajax event is completed. If it has, dont do preventDefault and return false. Instead do return true;.

Comment: it's only doing the AJAX request like it is for Marty's and axel.michael's answer.

Comment: Karan - You know what. if you press the submit button again it submits the action. I'll manage it that way. Thanks for your help mate. :D

Answer (score 1):

if you change this

```
 $("form").on("submit", function() {
    if(window.localStorage!==undefined) {
```

to

```
 $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(window.localStorage!==undefined) {
```

this will prevent the form from being submitted naturally...

!update: forgot to pass the event to the function! code updated.

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined

Comment: Right. That works but it doesn't run the external script `action="http://s33.t.eloqua.com/e/f2"` on the submit button.

Comment: thats because the event is preventing that from running, this will post data to your ajax.url: backend.php you could run another script from within that file, as long as you have permission to the external resource!

Comment: @Marty - By external source, do you mean backend.php or http://s33.t.eloqua.com/e/f2 ?

Answer (score 1):

When I get you right, your problem is based on the fact, that you want to do two totally different things after one submit. You could do this on a few ways.

Variant one: No Ajax, Post your Data, do whatever you do in backend.php and then use [curl to send post data](http://www.askapache.com/php/sending-post-form-data-php-curl.html) to the other server.

Variant two: In case you want to do this with ajax, you could try it this way:

```
// this is your old anonymus function a bit modified...
var ajaxSubmitHandler = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(window.localStorage!==undefined) {
        var fields = $(this).serialize();
        localStorage.setItem("eloqua-fields", JSON.stringify( fields ));
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "backend.php",
           data: fields,
           // and when ajax is done ... remove the event handler 
           done : function() {
                // deactivate submit handler....
                $("form").off("submit", ajaxSubmitHandler);
                // and simply retrigger the submit
                // this time it will only do the normal action
                $("form").submit();
           }
        });

    } else {
        alert("Storage Failed. Try refreshing");
    }
}

// per default you use the handler with the nested ajax request
$("form").on("submit", ajaxSubmitHandler);
```

Comment: Not sure if the 2nd variant works. Can you test it out locally with the original files: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mm1tdhr4fe6nstc/S4OT31LAiR
 Much obliged

Comment: No I won't do that, this is your project not mine, I gave an anwser, to implement it is your to do, takes you only a few minutes.

Comment: Right. I tried it and it did the same thing that Marty's solution did. i.e. AJAX works fine but the submit action script isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wait till both the ajax requests finish, you can make use of jquery deferred objects. That way, you can redirect to the other page only when both the request have been complete. Below is the simple sample code to use deferred objects.

```
var fn1 = $.ajax("/url-1.php");
var fn2 = $.ajax("/url-2.php");

$.when(fn1, fn2).done(function(fn1, fn2) {
  alert("all complete");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Vivek but if you see my code, one's an AJAX request and the other one's a submit action. What should I do with that?

Answer (score 0):

make a sync call to your php page by passing 'async:false' in your ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           async:false;
           url: "backend.php",         
           data: fields
        });
```

Comment: Not really a very good approach. Kinda defeats the purpose of ajax